# Is there any Android app that can detect particular text on screen and click on it automatically?

Tags: android, screen-scraping, text-recognition, android-app-ops

I want a app that can read text on my screen and click on the text which I can pre-define in the app. App mostly capable to identify multiple texts and if anyone of them present on screen then click on that region.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't have anything to do with programming. It may be on topic on another stack exchange site such as android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Macrodroid.

Use the Device action -> UI interaction -> Click -> Specific text

Option in the macro and it'll click that word on the screen

Comment: Did this work for anyone? I tried using a regular expression. It worked for someone else but not me. https://www.macrodroidforum.com/index.php?threads/text-contains-case-sensitive-screen-reader-on-screen-in-doordash-dasher-app.6032/

Answer (score -1):

You can't.  Android doesn't have APIs for screen scraping because its a huge security hole-  you could use it to grab passwords, banking info, etc.  Definitely not possible without a rooted device, probably not possible even with root without a lot of work (you could maybe on a rooted device grab it right from the screen data, but then you'd have to do image processing to find the actual text).